# C# passing data to another project

Tags: pass-data

I want to pass the UserID from my project to another project exe.
I call second project with these codes.

```
using System.Diagnostics;
private void MenuItemClickHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
startInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
startInfo.FileName = @"\\server1\Lawyer\Lawyer.exe";
startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
startInfo.Arguments = CurrentUser.UserID.ToString();
Process.Start(startInfo);
}
```

How can I pass the UserID of my project to second project that I called (Lawyer)?
Thanks so much

Comment: what problems are you having? The 2nd project must be coded to accept/read the parameters given to it.

Comment: This seems to be the way to go. i see no problems with this code.
What does the main method of Laywer.exe look like?

Comment: I have main project that calls other projects,like a desktop,I want to use the UserID and Pass that users write to enter the main project and pass them to the projects that call from main project without login form.